# Laravel "undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to associate related models during database seeding in Laravel 4. According to the documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models), I can do it like this:

```
$user->roles()->attach(1);
```

So, in my database seed I'm running:

```
$package = Package::create([
    'name' => $faker->word,
    'summary' => $faker->sentence,
    'base_price' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 200, 10000)
]);

// Attach 1-5 randomly selected items to this package
foreach(range(1, 5) as $index)
{
    $randomItem = Item::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->first();
    $package->items()->attach($randomItem->id);
}
```

The packages items have already been seeded at this point, and they seed without problems. The above code gives this from Artisan though:

```
[BadMethodCallException]                                              
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()
```

Someone [here](http://irclogs.laravel.io/2013-05-04/15:39) seems to think that the `attach()` method doesn't actually exist and the docs are wrong, but I find that hard to believe.

**TL;DR What is the correct way to create many-to-many relationships in Eloquent?**

Comment: You haven't shown us the code in your `items()` method.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The function `items()` in your **Package** model must return a **BelongsToMany** relationship in order to use `attach()`.

```
public function items() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('Item');
}
```

Comment: This was it. I thought hasMany and belongsToMany were used for many-to-many relationships - actually belongsToMany on both sides, as you say.