# How to fix 'Call to undefined method Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo::attach()'

Tags: laravel, eloquent

After running the following `$vehicle = App\Models\Vehicle::find(1);`
after running tinker I get the first vehicle but when I run `$vehicle->type()->attach(1);`to attach a type Toyota which has an id of 1 then I get the following error

```
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo::attach()'
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Vehicle.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vehicle extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Type');
    }
}
```

Type.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Type extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function vehicles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Vehicle');
    }

}
```

Comment: `belongsTo()` (one-to-one/one-to-many) doesn't have an attach method... `attach()`, `detach()` and `sync()` are methods for the `belongsToMany()` (many-to-many).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel "undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495130/laravel-undefined-method-illuminate-database-query-builderattach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't attach a model with a ont to many relationship,

you have to do one of these 2 methods :

Your vehicule already exists :

```
$type = Type::find(1);
$vehicle = App\Models\Vehicle::find(1);

$vehicle->update(['type_id' => $type->id]);
```

Or if it does'nt exist yet :

```
$type = Type::find(1);
$vehicle = App\Models\Vehicle::find(1);

$type->vehicles()->create([
  // Your vehicle attributes
]);
```

Comment: Getting the below error, I'm I supposed to include the type_id in the vehicles migration?

Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'type_id' in 'field list' (SQL: update `vehicles` set `type_id` = 1, `vehicles`.`updated_at` = 2020-11-23 20:02:20 where `id` = 1)'

Comment: I included the type_id in the vehicles migration and that worked. I also learned one to one/one to many relationship do not require a pivot table... Thanks a lot!